# How to parse JSON data into fragments?

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Hello friends im developing android app with fragments in a viewpager but now i want to parse JSON data into the fragment.my question is how can i set number of fragments as the size of json data and insert the json data into the required fragment.please help me ive been searching for it on internet for hours but disappointment results so please help me.Thanks in advance!.

```
[{"c_id":13,"category_name":"PUBLICATIONS","imagename":"http://goringr.com/church_project/churchimagesnew/publications.jpg","ctype":"church"},{"c_id":14,"category_name":"YOUTH ASSOCIATION","imagename":"http://goringr.com/church_project/churchimagesnew/youthassociation.jpg","ctype":"church"}]
```

this is my json data and all i want is to display contents of object with c_id=13 in first fragment and display contents of object with c_id=14 in second fragment.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package project1.test;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String data = "hello";
FragmentPagerAdapter adapterViewPager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   //        Toolbar tool = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.tool);
   //        setSupportActionBar(tool);
    //        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ViewPager vpPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
    adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sample_actions, menu);
    return true;
}

public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private static int NUM_ITEMS = 3;

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    // Returns total number of pages
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;
    }

    // Returns the fragment to display for that page
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return FirstFragment.newInstance(0, "Fragment1");
            case 1:
                return FirstFragment.newInstance(1, "Fragment2");
            case 2:
                return SecondFragment.newInstance(2, "Fragment3");
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    // Returns the page title for the top indicator
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Page " + position;
    }

}

}
```

**FirstFragment**

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
// Store instance variables
private String title;
private int page;

// newInstance constructor for creating fragment with arguments
public static FirstFragment newInstance(int page, String title) {
    FirstFragment fragmentFirst = new FirstFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("someInt", page);
    args.putString("someTitle", title);
    fragmentFirst.setArguments(args);
    return fragmentFirst;
}

// Store instance variables based on arguments passed
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    page = getArguments().getInt("someInt", 0);
    title = getArguments().getString("someTitle");
}

// Inflate the view for the fragment based on layout XML
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

;
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
 //        TextView tvLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvLabel);
 ////        tvLabel.setText(page + " -- " + title);


    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar1);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle("black panther");

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // TODO Add your menu entries here
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.sample_actions, menu);
}
}
```

**SecondFragment**

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {
// Store instance variables
private String title;
private int page;
Button tryit;

// newInstance constructor for creating fragment with arguments
public static SecondFragment newInstance(int page, String title) {
    SecondFragment fragmentSecond = new SecondFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("someInt", page);
    args.putString("someTitle", title);
    fragmentSecond.setArguments(args);
    return fragmentSecond;
}

// Store instance variables based on arguments passed
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    page = getArguments().getInt("someInt", 0);
    title = getArguments().getString("someTitle");
}

// Inflate the view for the fragment based on layout XML
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, 
   false);
    tryit = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.tryit);
    tryit.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),ManagingProfile.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
//        TextView tvLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvLabel);
//        tvLabel.setText(page + " -- " + title);
    return view;
}
}
```

Comment: how the fact that it's fragment makes any difference?

Comment: pardon me im a beginner just i month experience....i know how to parse json data in to custom listview but when it come to fragment im a bit confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can parse like this:

```
List<RidesData> ridesDatas;  /* this is should be parcelable */
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()); 
    adapter.addFragment(FragmentAbout.newInstance(ridesDatas), "ABOUT");
    adapter.addFragment(FragmentPointOfInterest.newInstance(ridesDatas),"POI");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

and set constructure to each fragment like this:

FragmentAbout.class

```
public static FragmentAbout newInstance(List<RidesData> ridesDatas) {
        FragmentAbout fragmentAbout = new FragmentAbout();
        Bundle arg = new Bundle();
        arg.putParcelableArrayList("data", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) ridesDatas);
        fragmentAbout.setArguments(arg);
        return fragmentAbout;
    }
```

FragmentPointOfInterest.class

```
public static FragmentPointOfInterest newInstance(List<RidesData> ridesDatas) {
        FragmentPointOfInterest fragmentPointOfInterest = new FragmentPointOfInterest();
        Bundle arg = new Bundle();
        arg.putParcelableArrayList("data", (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) ridesDatas);
        fragmentPointOfInterest.setArguments(arg);
        return fragmentPointOfInterest;
    }
```

and get each data of json in `onViewCreated()` method of fragment like this:

you have 2 position of data in json.

```
[0] = c_id=13
[1] = c_id=14
```

so in first fragment set 0 position:

```
RidesData data = ridesData.get(0);
```

and in second Fragment set 1 postion:

RidesData data = ridesData.get(1);

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        ridesData = new ArrayList<>();
        ridesData = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("data"); 
        RidesData data = ridesData.get(1);    
    }
```

Comment: Thanks bro for your response but these fragments are static sorry for not mentioning in my question that i need a dynamic fragments.consider a scenario in which a user adds one more JSON object(where c_id maybe 15 or any other) in the JSON array and i want to display it in automatically created fragment without creating the fragment statically using addfragment() method.assume as if there are 5 JSON objects in JSON  array and what i want is to automatically create 5 fragments to display each JSON object's content in each fragment.hope my explanation is clear.any help will be appreciated.

Comment: i already mention above..  im my example ridesData contain json data. in my rideData object position 0  = first json object data. position 1 = second object data..  no metter how many json object you add.. you can get by position.

Comment: and you dont have to create multiple fragment for each object.. you can fetch each position of json object in one Fragment. everytime it will display only perticular  position of json object data.

Comment: but you created the fragment using **adapter.addFragment()**method eg.`adapter.addFragment(FragmentPointOfInterest.newInstance(ridesDatas),"POI");` but i want fragments automatically created according to the number of JSON objects in JSON array...

Comment: try to understand this tutorial::   http://www.androidhive.info/2016/04/android-glide-image-library-building-image-gallery-app/

Comment: in my case second Fragment is for different purpose.. you should not create    dynamic fragment by Json objects...  first learn how to work fragment.

Comment: can you please help me creating dynamic fragments

Answer (score -1):

You have to make use of custom adapter to extract the json data and view holder to print the data. 
refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34443009/custom-arrayadapter-get-data-from-asynctask)

Comment: This is irrelevant to the fragment question.